# por que me sale ese error

Tags: python-3.x

por favor porq me sale error en kilogramo como no definido, soy nueva en este curso y recien estoy aprendiendo, ayuda por favor[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: supongo que es porque python distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas y kilogramos no está definido, ya que en esa línea está con minúsculas y en la variable con mayúsculas, las otras líneas también te darán error.

Comment: Como te comentan en la variable la pones la "K" con Mayúsculas y al imprimirlo la "k" en minúsculas. Son muy parecidas

Answer (score 1):

tu error se encuentra en la línea 12, ya que la K de kilogramo está en mayúscula, mientras que la que escribiste en la línea 24 está en minúscula. Lo que debes hacer es bien sea colocarlas ambas en minúscula o ambas en Mayúscula

Comment: muchas gracias, si despues tambien me di cuenta, gracias, siempre consultare ya que estoy en proceso de aprendizaje